# Jitsu has no method 'help' / Nodejitsu not ok?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodejitsu

I installed jitsu with the following command: sudo npm jitsu -g
It seems to have installed correctly but get the following error when running the command jitsu:
*/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/lib/jitsu/commands/help.js:101
 winston.help('');
TypeEror: Object #<Object> has no method 'help'*....... you get the point.

All other jitsu commands end in not ok.

Nodejs version: v0.4.11
npm: v1.0.27

Answer (score 4):

Two questions:

1. Are you running `jitsu` from the CLI? i.e. just: `jitsu help` or `jitsu`?
2. Do you have winston installed globally?

Give this a shot:

```
sudo npm uninstall jitsu winston -g  
sudo npm install jitsu -g  
jitsu
```